# Multiple insert using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysqldb to access a database in a Python script. I have the following select query

```
cHandler.execute("select 
                  from_unixtime(packet_log.analog_seconds), 
                       analog_log.parameter_id, analog_log.value,
                       analog_log.status from packet_log 
                       left join analog_log on 
                       packet_log.packet_id=analog_log.packet_id 
                       where analog_log.parameter_id in (378, 379, 380, 381,
                       382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389) 
                       order by packet_log.analog_seconds;")
```

I'm having trouble inserting this data into the local database. I need to insert the data according to the sensor in the `analog_log.parameter_id` field. For example, if `parameter_id=379`, the entry for this parameter should be inserted in column `'Co3'` in the local database. This has to be done for all the parameters in one insert. How can I do insert for all the parameters in the local database?

I want it to be like this

if `analog_log.parameter_id` = 379
 insert (Co3) value (analog_log.value)

if `analog_log.parameter_id` = 380
 insert (Co4) value (analog_log.value)

I'm having difficulty constructing this insert statement. The entire insert should be done for all the `parameter_id` in one step. Is it possible to skip a column or insert zero if `analog_log.value` was not received by the remote database for a particular `paramteter_id`?

Comment: Why are you inserting more than one value into a column?  That sounds like a very poor database design.

Comment: How can I do this for only one value per column?

Comment: I am slightly confused as to what you need to be done. Is it possible to have a sample result of what you want..? Also `This has to be done for all the multiple entries for all the parameters in one insert`  is one insert critical to your program? or is it just something that you want?

Comment: Can you please share us your table schema for local database?